# Why the MATLAB function **fitdist** does not include in the available range of distributions the Student-t?

Tags: matlab, statistics, risk-analysis

Why the MATLAB function **fitdist** does not include in the available range of distributions the Student-t? Is there an other way of fitting the Student-t and estimate the degrees of freedom $\nu$?

Comment: Have you tried: fitdist(x,'tlocationscale')

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply,

I have already tried but my series are supposed to not have trend and diffusion terms. My input data are actually the estimated residuals  resulting from the process $$X_{t}=\mu_{t}+\sigma_{t}Z_{t}$$, where Z are my residuals and $$\sigma_{t}$$ follows a  GARCH process.

Comment: Why...? Ask Mathworks I guess

Comment: `fitdist(x,'tlocationscale')` is correct - you can directly use it's nu value. mu should be zero by your description and sigma = nu/(nu-2) which simply is the variance of a standard t-dist.